# Output of the shape

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops, triangle

How can I improve code that would output this fixed-size shape to the console?

Shape:

```
#....
.#...
#.#..
.#.#.
#.#.#
.#.#.
#.#..
.#...
#....
```

I wrote the code, but it seems to me incorrect. Although he copes with this task. I want to combine all the elifs into an if, which is spelled out at the beginning. I think there is some kind of dependency between 10, 8, 6, 4 that will allow me to do this. I can't find this dependency to improve the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < 6; y++) {
            if ((x == y) or (x == (10 - y))) cout << "#";
            else if ((x == (8 - y)) and (x > y)) cout << "#";
            else if ((x == (6 - y)) and (x > y)) cout << "#";
            else if ((x == (4 - y)) and (x > y)) cout << "#";
            else cout << ".";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a purpose of doing it like that? If it's fixed size, just put it in a string.

Comment: Hint: What do 10, 8, 6 and 4 have in common?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I want to make the code more beautiful. I think we can do without the numbers 10, 8, 6, 4. There is some kind of connection between these numbers. I'm trying to figure out which one, it will make the code better. This is my purpose.

Comment: @tadman These are even numbers. I do not know how to apply it.

Comment: Hint: `!(y % 2)`

Comment: Re: _"more beautiful"_ - that's in the eye of the beholder. I think `std::cout << "#....\n.#...\n#.#..\n.#.#.\n#.#.#\n.#.#.\n#.#..\n.#...\n#....\n";` is pretty neat.

Comment: @tadman Should I replace 10, 8, 6, 2 to (y % 2) or what? I've tried but it didn't help me yet.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I agree. But it is a task where I can't write like this.

Comment: @tadman  Could you tell more about this idea, please?

Comment: From what I see, `#` is set where two conditions hold: indices are of same parity and `y` (which is horizontal according to your notation) coordinate is less or equal then both diagonal (starting at top left going downwards) and antidiagonal (starting at bottom left going upwards) on current (`x`) row.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk Yes, you are right. But how can I integrate this to my code?

Comment: @YurkoFlisk I understand how to write a condition for index evenness, but I don't understand how to write a condition for diagonals.

Comment: The top diagonal is `y == x` and bottom one is (assuming 1-based indexing as in your code) `y == 10 - x`. The condition that point `(x, y)` is to the left of both is trivial then.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk Yes, it is the solution

Comment: Consider something more generic. You can parameterize the entire thing with a single value (width), and so it makes sense to write a function that can output any size, including configurable characters: https://godbolt.org/z/5xbbzKqj6

Answer (score 2):

Employing a string `"#.#.#...."`, all you have to do for each line is decide which part of this string to display.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const std::string S = "#.#.#....";
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; ++row) {
        std::cout << S.substr(std::abs(row - 4), 5) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, I found my code was edited.
The Editor say "made into a MRE", but I don't know what is the word "MRE" (Abbreviation for something?)
I can understand adding include statements is good. Thanks.
But I don't know about other modification such as spacing format.
Is some recommended coding style defined in SO, and this modification is based on it?

Comment: That's abbreviation for Minimal Reproducible Example. See on [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).